# VB script to list files and folders output to html

Tags: vbscript

I have a VB script that I'm using at the moment and it's working well, but I'd like to have a way to specify what file types get listed and I'd also like to list the sub directories. Not the sub directory contents but just the names of them. This is what I have:

```
Dim ls, fsObj, fd,  fs, fl, tf

ls = ""
Set fsObj = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set fd = fsObj.GetFolder(".")
set fs = fd.Files


For Each fl in fs
  ls = ls & "<a href=""" & fl.name & chr(34) & Chr(62) & fl.name & chr

(60) & chr(47) & chr(97) & chr(62) & chr(10) & "</br>"
Next

Set tf = fsObj.OpenTextFile("dirlist.html", 2, True, True)
tf.WriteLine ls

tf.Close
Set fsObj = Nothing
```

I could probably be done easier and prettier but this works for me, apart from the folder and file type issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    Dim ls, fsObj, fd, fs, fl, sfs, sf, tf

    ' specify the file extensions to list
    dim fileTypes
    fileTypes = Array("pdf","txt","asp")

    ls = ""
    Set fsObj = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set fd = fsObj.GetFolder(".")
    set fs = fd.Files

    For Each fl in fs
        ' check whether the extension matches 
        if arrayContains(fileTypes, fsObj.GetExtensionName(fl.name)) then
            ls = ls & "<a href=""" & fl.name & chr(34) & Chr(62) & fl.name & chr(60) & chr(47) & chr(97) & chr(62) & chr(10) & "</br>"
        end if
    Next

    ' list subfolders
    set sfs = fd.SubFolders
    For Each sf in sfs
        ls = ls & "<a href=""" & sf.name & chr(34) & Chr(62) & sf.name & chr(60) & chr(47) & chr(97) & chr(62) & chr(10) & "</br>"
    Next

    Set tf = fsObj.OpenTextFile("dirlist.html", 2, True, True)
    tf.WriteLine ls

    tf.Close
    Set fsObj = Nothing

    function arrayContains (arr, val)            
        dim found
        found = false
        for i = 0 to ubound(arr)
            if arr(i) = val then    
                found = true
                exit for 
            end if
        next
        arrayContains = found            
    end function
```

Comment: Thank you very much Kevin works great!!!! I have another idea could this be put into an html page and have the output written to the same page as it's loaded?

Comment: Yep, you would just response.write the output instead of saving to a file.

Comment: Mate sorry but what does that mean? I'm just starting out with vb scripting. Haven't got to that chapter yet lol

Comment: @Greg posted what I mean in another answer.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a web page version.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>

<%

    Dim ls, fsObj, fd, fs, fl, sfs, sf, tf

    'specify the file extensions to list
    dim fileTypes
    fileTypes = Array("pdf","txt","asp")

    ls = ""
    Set fsObj = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set fd = fsObj.GetFolder(".")
    set fs = fd.Files

    For Each fl in fs
        'check whether the extension matches 
        if arrayContains(fileTypes, fsObj.GetExtensionName(fl.name)) then
            'ls = ls & "<a href=""" & fl.name & chr(34) & Chr(62) & fl.name & chr(60) & chr(47) & chr(97) & chr(62) & chr(10) & "<br>"
            response.write ( "<a href=""" & fl.name & chr(34) & Chr(62) & fl.name & chr(60) & chr(47) & chr(97) & chr(62) & chr(10) & "<br>" )
        end if
    Next

    ' list subfolders
    set sfs = fd.SubFolders
    For Each sf in sfs
        'ls = ls & "<a href=""" & sf.name & chr(34) & Chr(62) & sf.name & chr(60) & chr(47) & chr(97) & chr(62) & chr(10) & "<br>"
        response.write( "<a href=""" & sf.name & chr(34) & Chr(62) & sf.name & chr(60) & chr(47) & chr(97) & chr(62) & chr(10) & "<br>" )
    Next

    'Set tf = fsObj.OpenTextFile("dirlist.html", 2, True, True)
    'tf.WriteLine ls

    'tf.Close
    Set fsObj = Nothing

    function arrayContains (arr, val)            
        dim found
        found = false
        for i = 0 to ubound(arr)
            if arr(i) = val then    
                found = true
                exit for 
            end if
        next
        arrayContains = found            
    end function

%>
```